# How to define a Hibernate OneToOne unidirectional mapping in Parent where the FK column is in the child?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Background:
I'm in the process of upgrading to Hibernate 6.1.4 (from 5.3.x) and have run into problems with OneToOne bidirectional mappings (which *appears* to be a bug, and I've written up).  I'm looking for a workaround that doesn't require changing the schema and am considering making the mapping unidirectional but have run into an issue.

Here's a simplified version of the starting point:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PARENT_T")
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "PARENT_PK")
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = Child.class, mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Child child;

    // getters and setters...
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "PARENT_T")
public class Child {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "CHILD_PK")
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = Parent.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_FK", nullable = false)
    private Parent parent;

    // getters and setters...
}
```

So, I would like to remove the Child-to-Parent mapping, and just map the attribute:

```
    @Column(name = "PARENT_FK", nullable = false)
    private Long parentFK;
```

However, this means that the `mappedBy = "parent"` in the Parent is no longer valid.  I can add a JoinColumn annotation, but per the docs, the JoinColumn name is in the source entity (here, Parent):

> The name of the foreign key column. The table in which it is found depends upon the context.
>
> If the join is for a OneToOne or ManyToOne mapping using a foreign key
> mapping strategy, the foreign key column is in the table of the source
> entity or embeddable.

I saw a suggestion to use a OneToMany mapping, since:

> If the join is for a unidirectional OneToMany mapping using a foreign
> key mapping strategy, the foreign key is in the table of the target
> entity.

... and then treat it as a One-to-One.  However, this seems like a kludge.

So: Is there a way to map a OneToOne relationship where the foreign key column lies with the target entity (here: Child), rather than the source (here: Parent)?

Conceptually, I'm just looking for a table equivalent of mappedBy in the annotation, Something like:
@OneToOne(targetEntity = Child.class, mappedByColumn = "PARENT_FK", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try this mapping here:

```
@MapsId
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_PK", referencedColumnName = "PARENT_FK")
private Child child;
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work.  If the value is not present, rather than null, I get: `org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [com.....Child#80000042]`.   I had thought  it was working if a value was present, but since the PK value it is reporting, 80000042, is that of the Parent, I'm guessing it was just coincidence(since the parent and child entities just happen to have the same pk). @christian

Comment: Try removing the `@JoinColumn` part

Comment: Without the JoinColumn, there would be no way to know that PARENT_FK is the column to use in Child.  PARENT_FK is not the id of Child, @christian (and why can't I put the mention at the beginning of my comment.  It keeps removing it).

Comment: If `PARENT_FK` is not the primary key, I hope you made that column at least unique, or otherwise you might run into other trouble. Anyway, try removing `@MapsId` and use `@JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_PK", referencedColumnName = "PARENT_FK", insertable = false, updatable = false)`